# @Index does not work on JOINED subclasses?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, hibernate-annotations

My Hibernate annotations work when my application is running on the server, but when I try to test my Hibernate classes with JUnit I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name base_batch_id in table T_BASE_EXT
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.getPhysicalColumnName(Configuration.java:3550)
at org.hibernate.cfg.IndexOrUniqueKeySecondPass.addConstraintToColumn(IndexOrUniqueKeySecondPass.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.IndexOrUniqueKeySecondPass.doSecondPass(IndexOrUniqueKeySecondPass.java:77)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1423)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
at foo.BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:31)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I believe this has something to do with the `@Index` annotation at `BaseExt` class. My annotated classess are working and can't change them, but is there something that I can do to my Hibernate configuration in the JUnit test to get this working?

I've found a ticket that had a similar issue: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-207

Here is a JUnit test to replicate this error:

**Abstract base class:**

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "SEQ", initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQ_GEN")
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**Class that extends the abstract class:**

And it also has a ManyToOne relationship to BaseBatch-class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_BASE_EXT")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "T_BASE_EXT", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "IDX_CDA_1", columnNames = {"BASE_BATCH_ID"})
})
public class BaseExt extends Base implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ForeignKey(name = "CDA_BASE_BATCH_FK")
    private BaseBatch baseBatch;

    public BaseBatch getBaseBatch() {
        return baseBatch;
    }

    public void setBaseBatch(BaseBatch baseBatch) {
        this.baseBatch = baseBatch;
    }

}
```

**BaseBatch:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_BASE_BATCH")
public class BaseBatch extends Base implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

**The JUnit test:**

```java
public class BaseTest extends TestCase {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        final String driverClass = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driverClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
        .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driverClass)
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:basetest")
        .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Base.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(BaseExt.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(BaseBatch.class);

        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    public void testBase() {
        sessionFactory.openSession();
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I'm using Hibernate Annotations 3.2.0.Final and Hibernate 3.6.9.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this annotation on

```
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="base_batch_id"))
private BaseBatch baseBatch;
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding AttributeOverride annotation helped, I had to add the override as a class annotation though. Upvotes for you :)